Spark issue: ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
Could anyone please provide the resolution of this issue?
While running the code in the local setup I am getting the below error.
24/08/06 21:38:16 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
24/08/06 21:38:20 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

screenshot


Asking as a comment since it's not really an answer (if it works I can make it one): Do you have different pythons on your system than the one you are running this code with? Usually things like that are - in my experience - because spark is using the wrong python interpreter in the backend. If so, perhaps look into setting PYSPARK_PYTHON?
